# Combining java spring/thread and database access for time-critical web applications

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I'm developing an MVC spring web app, and I would like to store the actions of my users (what they click on, etc.) in a database for offline analysis. Let's say an action is a tuple (long userId, long actionId, Date timestamp). I'm not specifically interested in the actions of my users, but I take this as an example.

I expect a lot of actions by a lot of (different) users par minutes (seconds). Hence the processing time is crucial.

In my current implementation, I've defined a datasource with a connection pool to store the actions in a database. I call a service from the request method of a controller, and this service calls a DAO which saves the action into the database.

This implementation is not efficient because it waits that the call from the controller and all the way down to the database is done to return the response to the user. Therefore I was thinking of wrapping this "action saving" into a thread, so that the response to the user is faster. The thread does not need to be finished to get the reponse.

I've no experience in these massive, concurrent and time-critical applications. So any feedback/comments would be very helpful.

Now my questions are:

- How would you design such system?
  would you implement a service and then wrap it into a thread called at every action?
- What should I use?
  I checked spring Batch, and this JobLauncher, but I'm not sure if it is the right thing for me.
- What happen when there are concurrent accesses at the controller, the service, the DAO and the datasource level?

In more general terms, what are the best practices for designing such applications?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check this out, http://www.i-develop.be/blog/2010/10/01/execute-tasks-asynchronously-with-spring-3-0/, which sends emails asynchronously, So you create task executor and service, and add all action history

Comment: Logging the user actions for analysis is not critical for the current transaction, so i tmakes sense to store it asynchronously. Fire and forget into a jms queue will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a singleton object @ apps level and update it with every user action. 
This singleton object should have a Hashmap  as generic, which should get refreshed periodically say after it reached a threshhold level of 10000 counts and save it to DB, as a spring batch.

Also, periodically, refresh it / clean it upto the last no.# of the records everytime it processed. We can also do a re-initialization of the singleton instance , weekly/ monthly. Remember, this might lead to an issue of updating the same in case, your apps is deployed into multiple JVM. So, you need to implement the clone not supported exception in singleton.

Comment: Actually, this is what I'm doing at the moment, and it works pretty well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Typically it is considered bad form to spawn your own threads in a Java EE application.

A better approach would be to write to a local queue via JMS and then have a separate component, e.g., a message driven bean (pretty easy with EJB or Spring) which persists it to the database.

Another approach would be to just write to a log file and then have a process read the log file and write to the database once a day or whenever.

The things to consider are: -

- How up-to-date do you need the information to be?
- How critical is the information, can you lose some?
- How reliable does the order need to be?

All of these will factor into how many threads you have processing your queue/log file, whether you need a persistent JMS queue and whether you should have the processing occur on a remote system to your main container.

Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: thanks. Your solution is interesting. I'm wondering what is the overhead for this? 
As I understand, you drop the objects you need to process into a queue, and let another component process them, when resources are available...
To answer your questions,
a) I don't need these data to be very up to date. It is fine to store them in memory for a while, and dump the object from time to time in the database.
b) The data are critical. It is not acceptable to lose any.
c) the order does not matter since there is a timestamp coming from the request. thanks!

Comment: The overhead will depend on the system you are using, the number of messages, etc., but won't be massively more than using a thread and will certainly be a better approach. The overheads will really come from the fact that you can't lose any messages, you will have to use a persistent queue which will require writing to file or a database depending on your container/options! BTW I also like PATB's option below, there are several appenders you can use including JMS,  SNMP and even UDP for grapite depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the actions your users take, you should be able to figure that out from the HTTP requests they send, so you might be better off logging the incoming requests in an Apache webserver that forwards to your application server. Putting a cluster of web servers in front of application servers is a typical practice (they're good for serving static content) and they are usually logging requests anyway. That way the logging will be fast, your application will not have to deal with it, and the biggest work will be writing a script to slurp the logs into a database where you can do analysis.

Comment: Hi, I'm not specifically interested in actions of users. I took this as an example. I know that I could parse web server logs... but this is not the approach I'm considering.

Comment: Your questions says "I would like to store the actions of my users" but know you say "I'm not specifically interested in actions of users" You should clarify this in your question - people can only give answers that apply to the question asked ...

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did for that :

Used aspectJ to mark all the actions of the user I wanted to collect.
Then I sent this to log4j with an asynchronous dbAppender...

This lets you turn it on or off with log4j logging level.

works perfectly.